# Why isn't my user showing up in my DB given I should have the right code set up?

Tags: mongoose, passport.js, express-session, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

All the requirements are add and the page loads, it just doesn't save the new user to the db when I register a new one. Am following a tutorial/Bootcamp and I've gotten as far as the code below shows. Could anyone let me know where it seems to be an issue, given in the tutorial things are going right for the coder.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB'
mongoose.connect(url,  {useNewUrlParser:true}); 
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("login");
  });


  app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("register");
  });

  app.get("/secrets", function(req,res){
if (req.isAuthenticated){
  res.render("secrets");
} else {
  res.redirect("/login")
}
  })

app.post("/register", function(req,res){

User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err,user){

  if(err){console.log(err);
  res.redirect("/register")}
  else {
    passport.authenticate("local")(req,res, function(){
      res.redirect("/secrets")
    })
  }

})

  




});

app.post("/login", function(req,res){



  
 
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Thats my point. There is no problem from what I did an the tutorial did. Exact same code, different results on our db...

Comment: I restarted everything, mongo, node.. even rewrote the authentication code! Its all working now.